# How to sort the data order by a field cross/exist in two table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to sorting data order by a field  cross/exist in two table?
the sequence exist in folder table and file table, how to sort them together

query

```
SELECT * FROM folder fo 
  LEFT JOIN file fi ON fi.parent_folder_id = fo.id
WHERE fo.parent_folder_id = $1 AND fi.parent_folder_id = $1
  ORDER BY  fo.sequence fi.sequence ??   ;    <<  my problem 

[1]
```

data example

```
folder
id | sequence | parent_folder_id | name
1  | 0        |                  | root
2  | 0        | 1                | 
3  | 2        | 1                |

file
id | sequence | parent_folder_id |
1  | 1        | 1                |
```

output

```
folder(id:1, sequence:0 name:root)
  folder(id:2, sequence:0)
  file(id:1, sequence:1)
  folder(id:3 sequence:2)
```

Comment: If one record has fo.sequence < fi.sequence, and another has fi.sequence < fo.sequence, which comes first?

Comment: I want to combine them then order by like output in question

Comment: Are you sure `fo.parent_folder_id = $1 AND fi.parent_folder_id = $1` is correct? Don't you mean OR instead of AND?

Comment: Besides, what is the actual intention? Show all files and folders under a given folder?

Comment: yes I want to show all file and folders under a specific folder id

Comment: and order by sequence, but Idon't get how to merge sequence column in two  table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list all files and folders under first level of a given folder, then I recommend you use UNION ALL and get list of files and list of folders apart:

```
(
    SELECT 'folder' AS type, fo.id, fo.sequence, fo.name
    FROM folder fo
    WHERE fo.parent_folder_id = 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 'file' AS type, fi.id, fi.sequence, NULL
    FROM file fi
    WHERE fi.parent_folder_id = 1
)
ORDER BY sequence;
```

It is odd that you don't have name in files table, but I think it is probably just oversimplification of the problem. If you also want to include the parent folder in the listing, I'd just add it as another UNION ALL subquery with fixed lower possible sequence:

```
(
    SELECT 'folder' AS type, fo.id, -1 AS sequence, fo.name
    FROM folder fo
    WHERE fo.id = 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 'folder' AS type, fo.id, fo.sequence, fo.name
    FROM folder fo
    WHERE fo.parent_folder_id = 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 'file' AS type, fi.id, fi.sequence, NULL
    FROM file fi
    WHERE fi.parent_folder_id = 1
)
ORDER BY sequence;
```